# .NET MVC get path of a folder. Any Folder I need

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am new on .NET and created a project XYZ. In one of the controllers, I created QR codes and save them in XYZ/Content/Uploads as long as I hard code the path.

Something like  `img.Save("C:\\Users\\myusername\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\XYZ\\XYZ\\Content\\Uploads\\"+newname+ ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

When I deploy the project on Azure, obviously this doesn't work. I want to get physical path of the Content folder and so far the suggested  `Server.Path("~/Content/Uploads")` is simply not working.

Can someone tell me why on earth something so trivial has to seem so hard to come across, and point me in the right direction :)

Comment: What exactly "not working" when using `Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads")`?

Comment: The name "Server" does NOT exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application as root.

```
var folderRootPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload/");
```

or

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/Upload/")
```

or

```
 HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Upload/");
```

Comment: The last version worked! HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Upload/");